# How to use module in another file besides main.rs

Tags: rust, module, rust-cargo

I have 3 files in my src folder: 'main.rs', 'network.rs', and 'nodes.rs'. I would like to use a function I declared in nodes.rs in network.rs. I cannot seem to find a way to do this. All I can find online are ways to access the functions within main.rs.

main.rs:

```
mod network;
mod nodes;

fn main() {
    network::run();
}
```

network.rs

```
pub fn run() {
    newnode();
}
```

nodes.rs

```
pub fn newnode() {
    println!("Test");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the `nodes` modules, you need to navigate back to `main.rs` and then descend to the submodule. You can do that by either starting from the root of the crate (`main.rs` in this example) with the `crate` keyword (so `crate::nodes::newnode`), or, because `main.rs` is the parent module of `network`, accessing it via `super`: `super::nodes::newnode`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to call the functions with the full path, you need to explicitly refer to them in the appropriate module with `use`.

At the beginning of `network.rs`: `use super::nodes::newnode;`.

Answer (score 1):

What is nobody mentions and frustrated me is that if you want to use a module in another module which is not main you have to include it in the main.rs file. In other words, if you do not include a module in the main.rs it will not be accessible to other modules. Hope this helps some people.